# Is Facebook Analytics going away?

Tags: api, facebook, analytics

Is Facebook Analytics going away, after 30 June 2021? If yes, then do we have any alternative to explore the information and insights that are provided by Facebook Analytics API?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is, there will be no specific full-featured alternative.
I found this [article](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/facebook-analytics-is-shuttering-on-june-30/401143) that explains pretty well what are Facebook's existing alternatives for some of the analytics features.
other then that, there are (paid) 3rd party services that can do the job for you.
Also, you can check fb graph v11 [blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2021/06/08/introducing-facebook-graph-api-v11-marketing-api-v11) in which it is referred to.

Comment: "Facebook Analytics tool is going away". but does It will also impact the facebook graph api?